# Print a string that changes according to node number

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file like this one

```
<contents>
        <content loid="1.0.71719207" type="images"/>
        <content loid="1.0.71719207" type="images"/>
    <content loid="1.0.71719207" type="images"/>
    <content loid="1.0.71719207" type="images"/>
</contents>
```

With XSL I want to obtain the following XML:

```
<div class="Image_1"></div>
<div class="Image_2"></div>
<div class="Image_3"></div>
<div class="Image_4"></div>
```

So basically I need to perform a loop and for every `<xsl:for-each select="contents/content">` to print out `<div class="Image_N"></div`> where `N` is the number of the node.

I'm trying with Altova simulator, but I don't know how to increment `N` from 1 to number of nodes.

This is my code. I'm a beginner with XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"     encoding="utf-8" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"     doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" />
    <xsl:template match="/">

                        <xsl:for-each select="contents/content">
                                <div class="EM_Story_Image_N"></div>

                       </xsl:for-each>


    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend studying Michael Kay's Book "XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 Programmer's Reference" ([amazon link with kickback](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=as_li_qf_sp_sr_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=9325&index=aps&keywords=XSLT%202.0%20and%20XPath%202.0%20Programmer%27s%20Reference&linkCode=ur2&tag=bernhardwagne-20))

Here's a more cumbersome approach than using `position()`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"     encoding="utf-8" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"     doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head><title>Test conteggio</title>
            </head>
            <body>

                <xsl:for-each select="contents/content">
                    <xsl:variable name="count"><xsl:number level="any" count="content"/></xsl:variable>
                    <div class="Image_{$count}"></div>
                </xsl:for-each>

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content">
    <div class="Image_{position()}" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied to the OP's original XML:**

```
<contents>
  <content loid="1.0.71719207" type="images"/>
  <content loid="1.0.71719207" type="images"/>
  <content loid="1.0.71719207" type="images"/>
  <content loid="1.0.71719207" type="images"/>
</contents>
```

**...the desired result is produced:**

```
<div class="Image_1" />
<div class="Image_2" />
<div class="Image_3" />
<div class="Image_4" />
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no counting `for` loop in XSLT like you get in more procedural or OO languages, but you do have access to the position of the current node in the current list over which you are iterating via the `position()` function.

```
<xsl:for-each select="contents/content">
  <div class="EM_Story_Image_{position()}"></div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But note that `position()` depends crucially on the context - if you had, say

```
<contents>
  <content loid="1.0.71719207" type="images"/>
  <content loid="1.0.71719207" type="images"/>
  <content type="somethingelse" />
  <content loid="1.0.71719207" type="images"/>
  <content loid="1.0.71719207" type="images"/>
</contents>
```

then in a `<xsl:for-each select="contents/content">` the last `<content>` element would be position 5, but in a `<xsl:for-each select="contents/content[@type='images']">` the same node would be position 4.